# Scripts won't run on internet explorer 11 (ie11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a script below

```
var dt = new Date();
year  = dt.getFullYear();
month = (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
day   = dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = year+"."+month+"."+day;
```

It's a simple script that displays current date (year, month and day).

The problem is that for some reason it won't work on internet explorer 11. (I have javascript enabled). On browsers like mozilla, chrome it works fine. Maybe the script should be differently written just for ie11?

Comment: any errors in developer tools console? it's probably the `padStart` method - you'll need to write it yourself, or write a function to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `.padStart` method that is not supported by the IE

You should [check can i use](https://caniuse.com/?search=padstart) before dealing with IE :)

As an option, you can use the [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB) or from [here](https://github.com/behnammodi/polyfill/blob/master/string.polyfill.js). And here is [EN version for the padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

In case you have to support IE in production, I would advise you to check transpilers [(babel as example)](https://babeljs.io/) It allows you to use modern code without worrying about old browsers. The downside is that configuration might be a bit tricky. But it really worth it.

Comment: Better yet, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: For some reason - no polyfill there

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#see_also - but I wasn't talking about polyfills, I was talking about checking if you can use something rather than using `caniuse` which is .. 99% valid :p

Comment: Oh me stupid :) I prefer caniuse because you can check other functionality without changing the page. For IE it's very useful, cause it supports so little

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 11 is **too old** to support [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#browser_compatibility).

You should have seen an error message about it being `undefined` when you looked at the developer tools when you debugged your code in IE. You did [debug it](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/), didn't you?

It is a legacy browser that Microsoft only provides for the benefit of out-of-date intranet based web applications.

MDN links to a [couple of polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#see_also) if you really need to support it in new development. As a rule of thumb, you should be working to eliminate it from your organisation instead.